# Compute $\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{x^2\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Compute$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} \cdot \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^2\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$.

The primitive function of each one seems not elementary function.

I tried like this
$$
\int_0^1 \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} + \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^2\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}=\int_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm{d}(x-\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-x^2}},
$$
but it still does not work.

Actually, I can compute it by Gamma and Beta function. But I wonder is there other approach? Appreciate any help!

Comment: Since they have an expression involving the $\Gamma$ function, I don't think you can compute these integrals without using the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @Tuvasbien See my answer.

Comment: The integral is equal to $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{y^2\mathrm dx\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{1-(x^4+y^4)+(xy)^4}},$$ so that if you can find an appropriate coordinate change you should be able to evaluate it easily...

Comment: Can you give some hint about the coordinate change you use?

Comment: This is a special case of a calculation in Laplace's original calculation of the Gaussian integral, the seventh proof [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.299.1328&rep=rep1&type=pdf). (I don't think this observation can be turned into a Gamma-free answer, but it's interesting.)

Answer (score 6):

Use $\beta$ function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Let $x=\sin^{1/2} t$, then
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{-1/2}t ~ dt=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/4)}$$
Next, $$I_2=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{1/2}t~ dt=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/4)}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\Gamma(3/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(5/4)}$$
Then$$I_1.I_2=\frac{1}{16}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)^2}{\Gamma(5/4)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: The question explicitly asked for an approach not using gamma and beta functions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is another approach – elliptic integrals.

By Byrd and Friedman 214.05 and 318.02, the two integrals evaluate as follows:
$$\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}K(m=1/2)\right)\left(\sqrt2E(1/2)-\frac{\sqrt2}2K(1/2)\right)$$
This can be rewritten as
$$\frac12(K(1-1/2)E(1/2)+K(1/2)E(1-1/2)-K(1/2)K(1-1/2))=\frac\pi4$$
where we have used Legendre's relation.

Comment: I'm unfamilar with the elliptic integral, could you send me a reference on what these K m and E mean, because it seems super interesting.

Comment: @Neptune I've written up a monograph on such integrals and the corresponding elliptic functions [here](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Dounreay/-/blob/master/misc/elliptic-integrals-and-functions.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for sending this!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel. Thanks for the link ! Very interesting document. **Happy New Year !**

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That monograph is fine work, sir. Damn fine work. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

For the antiderivatives, make $x=\sin(t)$
$$I_1=\int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}=\int \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)}}=F\left(\left.t\right|-1\right) $$
$$I_2=\int \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx=\int \dfrac{1+\sin^2(t)-1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)}}dt$$ that is to say
$$I_2=\int \sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)}\,dt -I_1=E(t|-1)-F(t|-1)$$

Integrated between $0$ and $\frac \pi 2$
$$I_1=K(-1)\qquad I_2=E(-1)-K(-1)$$ $$I_1\,I_2=K(-1)\Big[E(-1)-K(-1) \Big]=\frac \pi 4$$